# Impala Last_Value() Not giving result as expected

Tags: sql, database, impala, resampling, qsqlquery

I have a Table in Impala in which I have time information as Unix-Time (with a frequency of 1 mSec) and information about three variables, like given below:

```
ts          Val1        Val2        Val3        
1.60669E+12 7541.76     0.55964607  267.1613        
1.60669E+12 7543.04     0.5607262   267.27805       
1.60669E+12 7543.04     0.5607241   267.22308       
1.60669E+12 7543.6797   0.56109643  267.25974       
1.60669E+12 7543.6797   0.56107396  267.30624       
1.60669E+12 7543.6797   0.56170875  267.2643
```

I want to resample the data and to get the last value of the new time window. For example, if I want to resample as 10Sec frequency the output should be the last value of 10Sec window, like given below:

```
ts                      val1_Last       Val2_Last       Val3_Last   
2020-11-29 22:30:00     7541.76         0.55964607      267.1613
2020-11-29 22:30:10     7542.3994       0.5613486       267.31238
2020-11-29 22:30:20     7542.3994       0.5601791       267.22842
2020-11-29 22:30:30     7544.32         0.56069416      267.20248
```

To have this result, I am running the following query:

```
select distinct *
from (
select ts,
last_value(Val1) over (partition by ts order by ts rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as Val1, 
last_value(Val2) over (partition by ts order by ts rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as Val2,
last_value(Val3) over (partition by ts order by ts rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as Val3 
from (SELECT cast(cast(unix_timestamp(cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP))/10 as bigint)*10 as TIMESTAMP) as ts , 
Val1 as Val1, 
Val2 as Val2, 
Val3 as Val3
FROM Sensor_Data.Table where unit='Unit1'  
and cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN '2020-11-29 22:30:00' and '2020-12-01 01:51:00') as ttt) as tttt 
order by ts
```

I have read on some forums that `LAST_VALUE()` sometimes cause problem, so I tried to achieve the same thing using `FIRST_VALUE` with `ORDER BY DESC`. The query is given below:

```
select distinct *
from (
select ts,
first_value(Val1) over (partition by ts order by ts desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as Val1, 
first_value(Val2) over (partition by ts order by ts desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as Val2,
first_value(Val3) over (partition by ts order by ts desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as Val3
from (SELECT cast(cast(unix_timestamp(cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP))/10 as bigint)*10 as TIMESTAMP) as ts , 
Val1 as Val1, 
val2 as Val2, 
Val3 as Val3
FROM product_sofcdtw_ops.as_operated_full_backup where unit='FCS05-09'  
and cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN '2020-11-29 22:30:00' and '2020-12-01 01:51:00') as ttt) as tttt 
order by ts
```

But in both cases, I am not getting the result as expected. The resampled time `ts` appeared as expected (with a window of 10Sec) but I am getting random values for `Val1`, `Val2` and `Val3` between 0-9sec, 10-19Sec, ... windows.

Logic wise this query looks fine and I didnÄt find any problem. Could anybody explain that why I am not getting the right answer using this query.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
last_value(Val1) over (partition by ts order by ts rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as Val1,
```

You are partitioning and ordering by the same column, `ts` -- so there is no ordering (or more specifically ordering by a value that is constant throughout the partition results in an arbitrary ordering).  You need to preserve the *original* ts to make this work, using that for ordering:

```
select ts,
        last_value(Val1) over (partition by ts_10 order by ts rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as Val1, 
        last_value(Val2) over (partition by ts_10 order by ts rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as Val2,
        last_value(Val3) over (partition by ts_10 order by ts rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as Val3 
from (SELECT cast(cast(unix_timestamp(cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP))/10 as bigint)*10 as TIMESTAMP) as ts_10, 
             t.*
      FROM Sensor_Data.Table t
      WHERE unit = 'Unit1' AND
            cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN '2020-11-29 22:30:00' and '2020-12-01 01:51:00'
     ) t
```

Incidentally, the issue with `last_value()` is that it has unexpected behavior when you leave out the window frame (the `rows` or `range` part of the window function specification).

The issue is that the default specification is `range between unbounded preceding and current row`, meaning that `last_value()` just picks up the value in the current row.

On the other hand, `first_value()` works fine with the default frame.  However, both are equivalent if you include an explicit frame.

Comment: @ZeeshanShareef . . . Well, that is a mysterious comment.  This should fix the problem you described in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is working but it has some problem. The value of ts_10 is repeated 10 times and similary the last values of `val1`, `val2` and `val3` is also repeated 10 times.
When I try to put `DISTINCT` before `ts_10` then I am getting error that it cannot be applied to the Analytical functions because it is also applied to `LAST_VALUE(Val1)`, `LAST_VALUE(val2)` and `LAST_VALUE(Val3)`. 
Is there any way that I can apply DISTINCT function only on the ts_10 so that I am not getting this error anymore.

Comment: @ZeeshanShareef . . . You still need the `select distinct`.  This is to show you what was wrong with the window functions.